# When my dynamic array resizes it results in removing the first item added name (shoppingCart.name)?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, input, output

I have an issue where when the array resizes when count == cartSize, the first added items' shoppingCart.name is now gone when we print it to console. I believe this is a memory leak, and printing garbage but I am not entirely sure. I believe the problem lies in resizeArray though... but that I am also not sure about.

```
typedef struct Item {
  char name[26];
  size_t quantity;
  double price;
}item;

void resizeArray(item **cart, int count, int size) {
  item *resizeCart;
  resizeCart = (item *) malloc(size * sizeof(item));
  /* If the resizeCart is null then it does not have enough memory */
  if (!resizeCart) {
    printf("\nThis cart does not have enough memory to store your request.\n");
  }
  /* Resizing using memcpy to new array, and free the previous cart from memory */
  memcpy(resizeCart, *cart, count+1);
  free(*cart);
}

int main() {
char option;
  int cartSize, count = -1;
  int i;
  item *shoppingCart;
  int c;
  /* Prompt user to enter how many items they would like to add */
  printf("Enter the number of items you want to buy: ");
  scanf("%d", &cartSize);
  getchar();

  shoppingCart = (item *) malloc(cartSize * sizeof(item));
  /* If the shoppingCart is null then program does not have enough memory */
  if (!shoppingCart) {
    printf("Unable to process request (Not enough memory)");
  }

  /* While shopping cart is valid, continue prompting user to add/print or quit program */
  while (shoppingCart) {
    printf("\n======= Menu =======\n(A)dd an item to shopping cart\n(P)rint the current list of items\n(Q)uit the program\n");
    option = getchar();
    do {
        c = getchar();
    } while (c != EOF && c != '\n');
    switch(option) {
      case 'A':
        count++;
        /* If the count of products is equal to the size, resize */
        if (count == cartSize) {
          cartSize = cartSize * 2;
          resizeArray(&shoppingCart, count, cartSize);
        }
        /* clear output buffer, and move buffered data to console */
        fflush(stdin);
        /* Ask user for input for product: name/quantity/price */
        printf("Enter name of product: ");
        fgets(shoppingCart[count].name, 25, stdin);
    /* scanf("%s", shoppingCart[count].name); */

        printf("Enter quantity of product: ");
        scanf("%u",(unsigned int *) &shoppingCart[count].quantity);

        printf("Enter price of product: ");
        scanf("%lf", &shoppingCart[count].price);
        getchar();
        
        break;
      case 'P':
        printf("\n");
        /* Iterate through the shoppingCart and print each item along
        * with its corresponding price and quantity
        */
        for(i=0; i <= count; i++) {
          printf("%-25s\n", shoppingCart[i].name);
          printf("\t%.2f", shoppingCart[i].price);
          printf("\t%u\n", (unsigned) shoppingCart[i].quantity);
        }
        getchar();
        break;
      case 'Q':
        /* Quit out of the program if the user enters 'Q' */
        printf("Thank you have a nice day!\n");
        exit(0);
      default:
        /* If user did not enter 'A' or 'P' then ask them to enter again */
        printf("Invalid choice. Please try again.\n");
    }
  }
  /* Free the memory used by shoppingCart */
  free(shoppingCart);
  return 0;
}
```

Terminal Output:

```
======= Menu =======
(A)dd an item to shopping cart
(P)rint the current list of items
(Q)uit the program
P

Black Beans
             
    0.98    3
2% Milk
                 
    1.99    2


======= Menu =======
(A)dd an item to shopping cart
(P)rint the current list of items
(Q)uit the program
A
Enter name of product: Large Organic Eggs
Enter quantity of product: 2
Enter price of product: 4.99

======= Menu =======
(A)dd an item to shopping cart
(P)rint the current list of items
(Q)uit the program
P

                         
    0.98    3
2% Milk
                 
    1.99    2
Large Organic Eggs
      
    4.99    2
```

Comment: You don't set the original pointer after resizing. `*cart = resizeCart;`

Comment: Are you talking about right after memcpy() in the resizeArray()?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: But you need to save the pointer to be freed. But better still, just use `realloc`. It is designed to resize and copy.

Comment: When I did that, the first name was there (but the rest weren't) and it was the first 4 lefts of the name, and then all the number values were 0 or 0.00..?

Comment: Even worse, our professor said we can't use realloc()...

Comment: Your memcpy size is wrong. It needs to be bytes not count of elements.

Comment: so, sizeof(cart)?

Comment: `sizeof(item)*count`

Comment: Thank you for your help